# Is there such a function in python string.remove?

Tags: python

C# - String.Remove Ex.

```
int j = 4;
string pages = "/.././ewcwe/";
pages = pages.Remove(j, 2);
// pages = "/../ewcwe/";
// delete ./
```

Is there such a function in python string.remove?

sorry, ********./****** -> ./

Comment: similar issue (somehow): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317500/how-can-i-splice-a-string

Comment: actually, you can probably find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python

Comment: What does the `2` mean? You seem to be removing 6 characters here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you need to extract the parts you want and create a new string from them:

```
s = pages[:4] + pages[10:]
```

Alternatively you can overwrite the existing string (as pointed out in the comment below):

```
pages = pages[:4] + pages[10:]
```

Comment: I don't know C# at all, but the example is `pages = pages.Remove(4, 2)`, in which `pages.Remove` appears to be returning its result rather than modifying `pages` as a side effect. So the immutability of strings appears to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own metod.

```
>>>s="vivek"
>>> def rep(s,st,ed):
...  return s[:st]+s[ed:]
...
>>> rep(s,2,3)
'viv'
```

Answer (score 0):

No strings don't have such a method

However if you use a bytearray it's easy to remove a slice

```
pages = bytearray(pages)
del pages[4:10]
```

Possibly what you are trying to achieve could be done better with a regular expression

Comment: a regular expression to remove 2 characters at a fixed position ? come on !

Comment: @AdrienPlisson To be fair, the OP did not specify any context. There might well be justification for using regexps.

Comment: @msvalkon then i would suggest considering a LALR(1) parser. hey, the OP did not speocify any context !

Comment: @AdrienPlisson, I can't even imagine how you realised that the question was limited to removing 2 characters at a fixed position.

Answer (score -2):

Simply No

need to use Regular Expressions for faster performance

Comment: come on, get real... you simply don't know how regular expression works !