# Loops and Strings in python

Tags: python

Given the strings `s1` and `s2`, not necessarily of the same length. Create a new string consisting of alternating characters of `s1` and `s2` (that is, the first character of `s1` followed by the first character of `s2`, followed by the second character of `s1`, followed by the second character of `s2`, and so on.

Once the end of either string is reached, the remainder of the longer string is added to the end of the new string. For example, if `s1` contained "abc" and `s2` contained "uvwxyz", then the new string should contain "aubvcwxyz". Associate the new string with the variable  `s3`.

My attempt is:

```
s3 = '' 
i = 0 
while i < len(s1) and i < len(s2): 
    s3 += s1[i] + s2[i] 
    i += 1 
    if len(s1) > len(s2): 
        s3 += s1[i:] 
    elif len(s2) > len(s1): 
        s3 += s2[i:]
```

Comment: You should give it a try yourself and let us see what you did and where you got stucked to help you out !

Comment: s3 = ''
for i in range(0, min(len(s1), len(s2))):
    s3 = s3 + s1[i] + s2[i]

Comment: Better post it in your Question...Never be shame of what you tried...:)

Comment: s3 = '' 
i = 0 
while i < len(s1) and i < len(s2): 
 s3 += s1[i] + s2[i] 
 i += 1 
if len(s1) > len(s2): 
 s3 += s1[i:] 
elif len(s2) > len(s1): 
 s3 += s2[i:]            what about this ?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the info you're currently giving us

Comment: Also, `"".join("".join(i) for i in zip(s1,s2))`

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, this will fail if `s1` and `s2` have different size

Answer (score 3):

```
s1 = "abcdefg"
s2 = "hijk"
s3 = ""
minLen = min(len(s1), len(s2))
    for x in range(minLen):
    out += s1[x]
    out += s2[x]
out += s1[minLen:]
print out
```

A couple of things to keep in mind. First, you can treat a python string like an array, and you can access the item at given index using brackets. Also, the second to last line makes use of splicing, for more information, see [How can I splice a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317500/how-can-i-splice-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `izip_longest` method from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.izip_longest) module, this way:

```
import itertools as it
s3 = ''.join(''.join(item) for item in it.izip_longest(s1,s2,fillvalue=''))
```

DEMONSTRATION:

```
>>> s1 = 'ABCDEF'
>>> s2 = '123456789'
>>> s3 = ''.join(''.join(item) for item in it.izip_longest(s1,s2,fillvalue=''))
>>> 
>>> s3
'A1B2C3D4E5F6789'
```

EDIT: in avoiding multiple `join`:

```
s3 = ''.join(c for item in it.izip_longest(s1,s2,fillvalue='') for c in item)
```

Comment: I would suggest the following to avoid the multiple joins (which are probably less efficient):`''.join(c for item in it.izip_longest(s1,s2,fillvalue='') for c in item)`

Comment: @tiho...thanks for the comment, will update the answer..:)

Comment: Although `izip_longest` was my first thought, i'm going to have to go with @altblahblah for "grader-friendliness" and "student comprehension". Thanks for trying to teach the OP protocol round here.

Comment: @msw, that's right, the OP seems to learn Python and altblahblah answer is more comprehensive, just like you said .. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'abc'
b= 'uxyz'
c=''
t=0

while t<len(a):
    c+=a[t]+b[t]
    t+=1

c+=b[t:]
print(c)
```

This should be the bare minimum for you to tweak some more so you learn from this.  I suggest adding some conditionals and turning it into a function so it can take so s1 and s2 can be any length and it will still work.  That'll be fun~

Answer (score 0):

In python3.x, the following code block works, because Python slices return all of elements in range or an empty string if the index values aren't valid for that string:

```
n = min(len(s1),len(s2))
s3=""

for i in range(0,n):
    s3 = s3 + s1[i] + s2[i]

s3 = s3 + s1[n:] + s2[n:]
```

Answer (score 0):

we can first decide which string is longer then write a for loop for that condition.

```
s3 = ""
i=0
if len(s1)>len(s2):
    for i in range(len(s2)) :
        s3 = s3 + s1[i] + s2[i]
        i=i+1
    s3=s3+s1[i:]
else:
    for i in range(len(s1)) :
        s3 = s3 + s1[i] + s2[i]
        i=i+1
    s3=s3+s2[i:]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 0
s3 = ''
minLen = min(len(s1),len(s2))
while i < minLen:
    s3 = s3+ s1[i] + s2[i]
    i += 1
if maxLen != minLen:
    s3 += s1[minLen:]+s2[minLen:]
```

Comment: How maxLen is used?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your answer by adding at least a few words to help explain it.