# Beginner Issue; string index out of range

Tags: python, string, indexing, range

```
# word reverser
#user input word is printed backwards

word = input("please type a word")

#letters are to be added to "reverse" creating a new string each time
reverse = ""

#the index of the letter of the final letter of "word" the users' input
#use this to "steal" a letter each time
#index is the length of the word - 1 to give a valid index number
index = len(word) - 1

#steals a letter until word is empty, adding each letter to "reverse" each time (in reverse)
while word:
    reverse += word[index]
    word = word[:index]
    print(reverse)

print(reverse)
input("press enter to exit")
```

Working to make a simple program that spells a user input word backwards and prints it back to them by "stealing" letters from the original and making new strings from them.
Trouble I'm having is this code spews back a string index out of range error at
reverse += word[index]
Help or a better way of achieving same result is mucho apreciado.

Comment: Put a `print(index, len(word))` line right before the `reverse +=...` line and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While others have pointed out multiple ways of reversing words in Python, here is what I believe to be the problem with your code.

`index` always stay the same. Lets say the user inputs a four letter word, like `abcd`. Index will be set to three (`index = len(word) - 1`). Then during the first iteration of the loop, `word` will be reduced to `abc` (`word = word[:index]`). Then, during the next iteration of the loop, on the first line inside it (`reverse += word[index]`) you will get the error. `index` is still three, so you try to access `index[3]`. However, since `word` has been cut short there is no longer an `index[3]`. You need to reduce `index` by one each iteration:

```
while word:
    reverse += word[index]
    word = word[:index]
    index -= 1
```

And here is yet another way of reversing a word in Python (Wills code is the neatest, though):

```
reverse = "".join([word[i-1] for i in range(len(word), 0, -1)])
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Reversing a word in python is simpler than that:

```
reversed = forward[::-1]
```

I wouldn't use a loop, it's longer and less readable.

Comment: Python strings do not have a `pop` function.

Comment: How embarrassing, I always thing of strings as lists.  Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use the ["range"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function.

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

Returns a list from start to stop increasing (or decreasing) by step. Then you can iterate through the list. All together, it would look something like this:

```
for i in range(len(word) -1, -1, -1):
    reverse += word[i]
    print(reverse)
```

Or the easier way would be to use [string slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317500/how-can-i-splice-a-string) to reverse the word directly and then iterate through that. Like so:

```
for letter in word[::-1]:
    reverse += letter
    print(reverse)
```

With the way it is written now, it will not only print the word backwards, but it will also print each part of the backwards word. For example, if the user entered "Hello" it would print

```
o
ol
oll
olle
olleH
```

If you just want to print the word backwards, the best way is just

```
print(word[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not changing the value of the `index`

**modification:**

```
while word:
    reverse += word[index]
    word = word[:index]
    index-=1
print(reverse)`
```

that is you have to reduce index each time you loop through to get the current last letter of the `word`